# Have we that $\ell\ell({_{A}N})=\ell\ell(_{B}{N}) \;?$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two artin algebras.

Let $_{A}M_{B}$ be a bimodule.
 We denote ${\rm rad}({_{A}M})$ by the radical of $M$ as left $A$-module,
 We denote ${\rm rad}({M}_{B})$ by the radical of $M$ as rigtht $B$-module,
 We denote ${\rm rad}({_{A}M}_{B})$ by the radical of $M$ as bimodule.
We denote $\ell\ell(_{A}M)$ by the Loewy length of a left module $_{A}M$,
$\ell\ell(M_{B})$ by the Loewy length of a right module $M_{B}$, and
$\ell\ell(_{A}M_{B})$ by the Loewy length of a bimodule module $_{A}M_{B}$.

Problem:

$(1)$ Have we that ${\rm rad}({_{A}M})={\rm rad}({M}_{B})={\rm rad}
({_{A}M}_{B})$ as abelian groups?

$(2)$ $\ell\ell({_{A}M})=\ell\ell({M}_{B})=\ell\ell
({_{A}M}_{B})$ ?

$(3)$ If $f:A \longrightarrow B$ is a homomorphism of algebras $A$ and $B$, for a left $B$-module $_{B}N$, it also has a left $A$-module structure, that is, for $a\in A , x\in N$, we define $a.x=f(a)x$.

$$\ell\ell({_{A}N})=\ell\ell(_{B}{N}) \;?$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, in all 3 cases. For example take $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ and $B=k$ and $M=A$. 
Then $\operatorname{rad}(_A M)=(x)$ and $\operatorname{rad}(_B M)=0$. Thus, the Loewy length is 2 in the first case and 1 in the second. The same example works for the embedding $B\to A$ in (3).